# "Error C1060: compiler is out of heap space" when trying to compile a 550x550 Vector made of 4 character strings

Tags: c++

This program is designed to read an array/vector of strings (e.g. 0101) in a grid to show and solve maze's. It works when inputting a 20x20 array however receives "Error C1060: compiler is out of heap space" when trying to compile and run the 550x550 vector.

I've added /Zm200 to the project properties along with increasing the heap commit size exponentially.

I'm running x64 bit Windows 10 with 8GB RAM and using Visual Studio Professional 2017

```
// MazeBreaker.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins && ends there.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//Creating Variables

vector<vector<string>> ExampleMaze = {
    {"1110", "1100", "1111", "1001", "1101", "1000", "1101", "1010", "1001", "1111", "1010", "1001", "1111", "1110", "1111", "1111", "1101", "1010", "1110", "1100"},
    {"0111", "0110", "0010", "0000", "1111", "1000", "1011", "0000", "1010", "1010", "1110", "0011", "0011", "0010", "1001", "1011", "0001", "0110", "1010", "0101"},
    {"0110", "1110", "1000", "1100", "1010", "0001", "1111", "1100", "0000", "0010", "0011", "0110", "0000", "1110", "0000", "1000", "1111", "0011", "0001", "1101"},
    {"0111", "0011", "0000", "0011", "1111", "0100", "1011", "0011", "1100", "0011", "0111", "0011", "0110", "1001", "1100", "0111", "0000", "1001", "0011", "1111"},
    {"0101", "1110", "0001", "1010", "1101", "0001", "0001", "1010", "1000", "1011", "0110", "1000", "0011", "1010", "0100", "0001", "0000", "1001", "1001", "1111"},
    {"1100", "0010", "1000", "1000", "0001", "1101", "1010", "1011", "1010", "0110", "0011", "1000", "0000", "1111", "1000", "0011", "1011", "1011", "0111", "1101"},
    {"1100", "1110", "0011", "0110", "1100", "0100", "1110", "0010", "0000", "0011", "0110", "1100", "1001", "0001", "0111", "0011", "0000", "0001", "0111", "1101"},
    {"1110", "1011", "1011", "0000", "0110", "1101", "1001", "0001", "0100", "0101", "1111", "1101", "0000", "1010", "0110", "0101", "0001", "0011", "0111", "1011"},
    {"0110", "1110", "1101", "1100", "0010", "1000", "0010", "0110", "1000", "0110", "0001", "1100", "0001", "0111", "1010", "0110", "0000", "1011", "0110", "0101"},
    {"0111", "0101", "0100", "0110", "0001", "1000", "1010", "1001", "0110", "1000", "0110", "1011", "1100", "0011", "1110", "1001", "0100", "0100", "0110", "0101"},
    {"1110", "1100", "1110", "0010", "0111", "0100", "1100", "0100", "1101", "1100", "0110", "0101", "1110", "1001", "0111", "0110", "0011", "1011", "1111", "1011"},
    {"1111", "0101", "0010", "0101", "0110", "1000", "1100", "1011", "1010", "0001", "1110", "1101", "0100", "1010", "1000", "0000", "1011", "0111", "0010", "0111"},
    {"0111", "1111", "1001", "0100", "0101", "0101", "1010", "1100", "1101", "0101", "0011", "0111", "0011", "0000", "1101", "0010", "0101", "1010", "0100", "1111"},
    {"1111", "1010", "0000", "0110", "1111", "1000", "1010", "0100", "1110", "0100", "1110", "0110", "0101", "1111", "1010", "1100", "0001", "0011", "0101", "0001"},
    {"1101", "1111", "1101", "1110", "0011", "0001", "0101", "1001", "0101", "0101", "1000", "1111", "0111", "0100", "1101", "1010", "0001", "0111", "0001", "1111"},
    {"0110", "0001", "1100", "0110", "0110", "0000", "1110", "1011", "1001", "1100", "0100", "1000", "0011", "0010", "0111", "0100", "0100", "0101", "1011", "1011"},
    {"0110", "1011", "1101", "0010", "1111", "1101", "1010", "1000", "1000", "1111", "1111", "1011", "0101", "0001", "1101", "1010", "0101", "1011", "0100", "1111"},
    {"1100", "1001", "1011", "1010", "1101", "0111", "0100", "0110", "0110", "1100", "1110", "1101", "1110", "0001", "0100", "0001", "0001", "0100", "0111", "1001"},
    {"1110", "1101", "1100", "0110", "0100", "1101", "1001", "0110", "1011", "0001", "0100", "0011", "0110", "1111", "1101", "0110", "1100", "1011", "1100", "0011"},
    {"0111", "1110", "1110", "0110", "0011", "0111", "0011", "1011", "0110", "0010", "1011", "1011", "0010", "1111", "0111", "0110", "1011", "0010", "0010", "0111"}
    };

vector<vector<string>> ExampleMaze2 = {
     {"1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1000", "1000", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1011", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1000", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1011", "1100", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1110", "1000", "1011", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1110", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1101", "1100", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1001", "1110", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1000", "1000", "1001", "1100", "1010", "1010", "1010", "1001", "1100", "1001"},
     //..................... * 549

    };


vector<string> DrawMaze(vector<vector<string>> Maze, int StartX, int StartY, int FinishX, int FinishY)
{

    vector<string> MazePath;

    int Rows = Maze.size();
    int Columns = Maze[0].size();

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j = ++j)
        {
            string PrintLayers = "";

            for (int k = 0; k < Columns; k = ++k)
            {

                bool CheckStartFinish = false;

                if (((StartX == k) && (StartY == i)) || ((FinishX == k + 1) && (FinishY == i + 1)))
                {
                    CheckStartFinish = true;
                }

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+  ";
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+--";
                    }
                }
                else if (j == 1)
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        if (CheckStartFinish == false)
                        {
                            PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "   ";
                        }
                        else if (CheckStartFinish == true)
                        {
                            if (StartX == k)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " ST";
                            }
                            if (FinishX == k + 1)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " FN";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        if (CheckStartFinish == false)
                        {
                            PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|  ";
                        }
                        if (CheckStartFinish == true)
                        {
                            if (StartX == k)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|ST";
                            }
                            if (FinishX == k + 1)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|FN";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ((j == 0) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+";
                }
                else if ((j == 1) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|";
                }
                if ((i + 1 == Rows) && (j == 2))
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+  ";
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+--";
                    }
                }
                if ((i + 1 == Rows) && (j == 2) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+";
                }

            }

            if (!PrintLayers.empty())
            {
                cout << PrintLayers << endl;
                MazePath.push_back(PrintLayers);
            }
        }
    }
    return MazePath;
}

vector<string> ShowPath(vector<vector<string>> Maze, int StartX, int StartY, int FinishX, int FinishY)
{
    vector<string> MazePath;

    int Rows = Maze.size();
    int Columns = Maze[0].size();

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j = ++j) 
        {
            string PrintLayers;

            for (int k = 0; k < Columns; k = ++k)
            {

                bool CheckStartFinish = false;

                if (((StartX == k) && (StartY == i)) || ((FinishX == k + 1) && (FinishY == i + 1)))
                {
                    CheckStartFinish = true;
                }

                if (j == 0) 
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0') 
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " XX";
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "   ";
                    }
                }
                else if (j == 1) 
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        if (CheckStartFinish == false) 
                        {
                            PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "XXX";
                        }
                        else if (CheckStartFinish == true)
                        {
                            if (StartX == k) 
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "XST";
                            }
                            if (FinishX == k + 1) 
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "XFN";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        if (CheckStartFinish == false) 
                        {
                            PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " XX";
                        }
                        if (CheckStartFinish == true) 
                        {
                            if (StartX == k) 
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " ST";
                            }
                            if (FinishX == k + 1) 
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " FN";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ((j == 0) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " ";
                }
                else if ((j == 1) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " ";
                }
                if ((i + 1 == Rows) && (j == 2))
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " XX";
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "   ";
                    }
                }
                if ((i + 1 == Rows) && (j == 3) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " ";
                }

            }

            if (!PrintLayers.empty())
            {
                //cout << PrintLayers << endl;
                MazePath.push_back(PrintLayers);
            }
        }
    }
    return MazePath;
}

vector<vector<int>> FindPaths(vector<string> MazePath)
{
    int xPos = 0;
    int yPos = 0;

    int TrueXPos = (1 + (xPos * 3));
    int TrueYPos = (1 + (yPos * 2));

    bool N = true;
    bool E = true;
    bool S = true;
    bool W = true;

    vector<string> Path;
    string Direction = "N";
    Path.push_back(Direction);
    int i = 0;

    vector<string> DirectionOrder = { "N", "E", "S", "W" };
    string TempDirection;
    string DirectFrom = "N";
    vector<vector<int>> RouteCoords = { {0,0} };

    while (((N == true) || (E == true) || (S == true) || (W == true)) && (i < 60)) 
    {
        vector<string> Possibilities = {};
        N = false;
        E = false;
        S = false;
        W = false;

        if ((TrueYPos - 1 > 0) && (TrueYPos - 1 < MazePath.size()) && (TrueXPos > 0) && (TrueXPos < MazePath[0].size())) 
        {
            if (MazePath[TrueYPos - 1][TrueXPos] != ' ')
            {
                N = true;
                Possibilities.push_back("N");
            }
        }

        if ((TrueYPos > 0) && (TrueYPos < MazePath.size()) && (TrueXPos +2 > 0) && (TrueXPos + 2 < MazePath[0].size()))
        {
            if (MazePath[TrueYPos][TrueXPos + 2] != ' ')
            {
                E = true;
                Possibilities.push_back("E");
            }
        }

        if ((TrueYPos + 1 > 0) && (TrueYPos + 1 < MazePath.size()) && (TrueXPos > 0) && (TrueXPos < MazePath[0].size()))
        {
            if (MazePath[TrueYPos + 1][TrueXPos] != ' ')
            {
                S = true;
                Possibilities.push_back("S");
            }
        }

        if ((TrueYPos > 0) && (TrueYPos < MazePath.size()) && (TrueXPos - 1 > 0) && (TrueXPos - 1 < MazePath[0].size()))
        {
            if (MazePath[TrueYPos][TrueXPos - 1] != ' ')
            {
                W = true;
                Possibilities.push_back("W");
            }
        }



        if (MazePath[TrueYPos][TrueXPos] == 'F')
        {
            cout << "Finished" << endl;
            return RouteCoords;
        }
        if (MazePath[TrueYPos-1][TrueXPos] == 'F')
        {
            cout << "Finished" << endl;
            return RouteCoords;
        }
        if (MazePath[TrueYPos][TrueXPos+2] == 'F')
        {
            cout << "Finished" << endl;
            return RouteCoords;
        }
        if (MazePath[TrueYPos+1][TrueXPos] == 'F')
        {
            cout << "Finished" << endl;
            return RouteCoords;
        }
        if (MazePath[TrueYPos][TrueXPos-1] == 'F')
        {
            cout << "Finished" << endl;
            return RouteCoords;
        }

        for (int z = 0; z < 4; ++z)
        {
            //cout << "Checking: " << DirectionOrder[z] << "    ";
            //cout << "N: " << N << " E: " << E << " S: " << S << " W: " << W << endl;

            if ((N == true) && (DirectionOrder[z] == "N"))
            {
                cout << "Move North" << endl;
                Direction = "N";
                yPos += -1;
                DirectFrom = "S";
                cout << "X: " << xPos << " Y: " << yPos << endl;
                break;
            }
            if ((S == true) && (DirectionOrder[z] == "S"))
            {
                cout << "Move South" << endl;
                Direction = "S";
                yPos += 1;
                DirectFrom = "N";
                cout << "X: " << xPos << " Y: " << yPos << endl;
                break;
            }
            if ((W == true) && (DirectionOrder[z] == "W"))
            {
                cout << "Move West" << endl;
                Direction = "W";
                xPos += -1;
                DirectFrom = "E";
                cout << "X: " << xPos << " Y: " << yPos << endl;
                break;
            }
            if ((E == true) && (DirectionOrder[z] == "E"))
            {
                cout << "Move East" << endl;
                Direction = "E";
                xPos += 1;
                DirectFrom = "W";
                cout << "X: " << xPos << " Y: " << yPos << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        Path.push_back(Direction);
        auto itr = std::find(DirectionOrder.begin(), DirectionOrder.end(), DirectFrom);
        if (itr != DirectionOrder.end()) DirectionOrder.erase(itr);
        DirectionOrder.push_back(DirectFrom);

        RouteCoords.push_back({xPos,yPos});
        TrueXPos = (1 + (xPos * 3));
        TrueYPos = (1 + (yPos * 2));
        i += 1;
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < RouteCoords.size(); ++b) 
    {
        cout << "{";

        for (int c = 0; c < RouteCoords[b].size(); ++c) 
        {
            cout << RouteCoords[b][c] << ",";
        }
        cout << "},";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return RouteCoords;
}

void  MapRoute(vector<vector<string>> Maze, int StartX, int StartY, int FinishX, int FinishY, vector<vector<int>> RouteCoords)
{

    vector<string> MazePath;

    int Rows = Maze.size();
    int Columns = Maze[0].size();
    bool AddRoute = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j = ++j)
        {
            string PrintLayers = "";

            for (int k = 0; k < Columns; k = ++k)
            {
                AddRoute = false;
                for (int c = 0; c < RouteCoords.size(); ++c) 
                {
                    if ((RouteCoords[c][0] == k) && (RouteCoords[c][1] == i)) 
                    {
                        AddRoute = true;
                    }
                }

                bool CheckStartFinish = false;

                if (((StartX == k) && (StartY == i)) || ((FinishX == k + 1) && (FinishY == i + 1)))
                {
                    CheckStartFinish = true;
                }

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+  ";
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+--";
                    }
                }
                else if (j == 1)
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        if (CheckStartFinish == false)
                        {
                            if (AddRoute == true) 
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " XX";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "   ";
                            }
                        }
                        else if (CheckStartFinish == true)
                        {
                            if (StartX == k)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " ST";
                            }
                            if (FinishX == k + 1)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + " FN";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        if (CheckStartFinish == false)
                        {
                            if (AddRoute == true)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|XX";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|  ";
                            }
                        }
                        if (CheckStartFinish == true)
                        {
                            if (StartX == k)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|ST";
                            }
                            if (FinishX == k + 1)
                            {
                                PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|FN";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ((j == 0) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+";
                }
                else if ((j == 1) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "|";
                }
                if ((i + 1 == Rows) && (j == 2))
                {
                    if (Maze[i][k][j] == '0')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+  ";
                    }
                    else if (Maze[i][k][j] == '1')
                    {
                        PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+--";
                    }
                }
                if ((i + 1 == Rows) && (j == 2) && (k + 1 == Maze.size()))
                {
                    PrintLayers = PrintLayers + "+";
                }

            }

            if (!PrintLayers.empty())
            {
                cout << PrintLayers << endl;
                MazePath.push_back(PrintLayers);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}


int main()
{
    //cout << ExampleMaze[0][0][0] << endl;
    //DrawMaze(ExampleMaze, 0, 0, 20, 20);
    cout << endl;
    MapRoute(ExampleMaze2,0,0,20,20,FindPaths(ShowPath(ExampleMaze2, 0, 0, 20, 20)));

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your problem, why do you hard-code all that? Can't you use a file that you read when (and if) needed?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Currently it uses a hard-coded vector because it gets information from it such as sizes. This is then used to create another vector which shows all the paths that exist within the maze, which is then read and analysed to calculate the final maze solution.

The code is a translation from a initial piece of python code i created, which had no issue handling such large arrays.

I'm not sure how it would work if using a file, since it needs access to different sizes, positions and lines of the vector and i don't know how line and positional access works with a txt and c++.

Comment: A simple text file containing the strings could easily be read into your vectors. While it would affect the start-up time of the program it won't be by much. It will also be more flexible if you're going to continue to develop the program, especially since you can then load new data on-demand. And most importantly of all, it won't put much strain on the compiler.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have to check that out. Is it possible to read a line from a text file in the format of a vector, and then set it as a vector variable? As I know with Python you can just read a txt in the format of an array, and then convert is into a array variable.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have to check that out. Is it possible to read a line from a text file in the format of a vector, and then set it as a vector variable? As I know with Python you can just read a txt in the format of an array, and then convert is into a array variable.

Comment: Begin reading about [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). Continue to read about [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and the [`std::vector` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (there's one taking a pair of iterators). Lastly read about [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You just need a few lines of code to read the full file.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help, I'll take a look at it and see where it goes.

Comment: I felt bored, [here's an example to show how it could be done](https://ideone.com/Yv6W0c). Should work equally well passing an `std::ifstream` object to the reading function (which you basically can copy verbatim if you like). The dimensions doesn't matter for the code, the only limit is your systems memory running the program.

Comment: Much appreciated my good sir, should have it up and running in no time!